# Pig script to join on two columns in one table with one column in another table

Tags: join, apache-pig

```
empdoc = load 'file_name' using PigStorage('\t') as (emp_id : chararray, emp_code : chararray, employee_internal_id : int);

masterdoc = load 'file_name' using PigStorage('\t')as (emp_internal_id : int, emp_id : chararray, mother_id : int, father_id : int, section_code : chararray);

childone = JOIN empdoc by (employee_internal_id), masterdoc by (mother_id) OR masterdoc by(father_id);

genone = FOREACH childone GENERATE employee_internal_id, emp_internal_id,emp_id, ;
```

Basically I am trying to run the OR(as in SQL query) where employee_internal_id = mother_id or father_id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
empdoc = load 'file_name' using PigStorage('\t') as (emp_id : chararray, emp_code : chararray, employee_internal_id : int);

masterdoc = load 'file_name' using PigStorage('\t')as (emp_internal_id : int, emp_id : chararray, mother_id : int, father_id : int, section_code : chararray);

firstjoin = JOIN empdoc by (employee_internal_id), masterdoc by (mother_id) ;

genone = FOREACH firstjoin GENERATE employee_internal_id, emp_internal_id,emp_id ;

secondjoin=JOIN genone by (employee_internal_id) LEFT OUTER , masterdoc by (father_id) ;

result = FOREACH secondjoin GENERATE employee_internal_id, emp_internal_id,emp_id ;
```

Comment: Fails with ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line 12, column 0.  Encountered: <EOF> after : ""

Comment: The script worked now but I get more records than I expect. I am trying to run through a tree building from parent and going down to the children for 5 generations